# Статический блок и пример

Tags: java

Не очень понимаю почему такой пример, вообще что обычный, что статический блок сделаны для того, чтобы инициализировать переменные как я понял, а тут такое. Можете подсказать пожалуйста либо предложить свой пример.

```
public class StaticBlock {
        static String a;
    
        static {
            System.out.println("Статический блок инициализирован.");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            a = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("a = " + a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *This block gets executed when the class is loaded in the memory. A class can have multiple Static blocks, which will execute in the same sequence in which they have been written into the program.*

Comment: @entithat это понятно, но многие суют в эти статические блоки разные конструкции, хотел по этому поводу проконсультироваться и увидеть какой-нибудь возможно пример как правильно это делать, а как делать к примеру не стоит

Comment: @entithat я думаю, если автор хотел бы получить ответ на английском - он бы не писал на РУССКОМ stackoverflow

Comment: А обращатся к переменным в статическом блоке извне статического блока можно? Или даст эксепшн?

Comment: @ThePrettyFace, если переменные объявлены в статическом блоке, то только там они и будут видны

Comment: Если подумать, то блоки инициализации какраз удобное место для того что-бы добавить туда незамысловатую и небольшую логику инициализации переменной. Вить именно в блоке мы можем писать больше чем одну строку для инициализации. В данном примере для такой инициализации и испольозовался такой подход, поскольку просто будет не возможно с помощью такой же логики сразу присвоить значение константе.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, я процитировал. Есть переводчик, если что :)